# Deploying Laravel to Elastic Beanstalk - DB Connection Refused

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-5.5

I've been developing Laravel app and deploying regularly to an Elastic Beanstalk instance without issue, but suddenly, and without warning, deployments have begun to fail.

Obviously I immediately wondered what I might have changed in the code to cause this, but I haven't made any changes to the core configuration. I rolled back to an earlier commit just to make sure it wasn't my code, and I got the same error.

It's failing after I run `eb deploy` and running the `.ebextensions` configs.

Here's the error message from the logs:

```
[2018-01-08T10:50:34.672Z] INFO  [9457]  : Running 4 of 5 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild... 
[2018-01-08T10:50:35.523Z] ERROR [9457]  : Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError) caused by:   

In Connection.php line 664:
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = custom and table_name
= migrations)

     In Connector.php line 67:
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

      (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

The DB connection credentials are absolutely correct (and haven't changed either).

The command that it's attempting when it fails is simply:

`php artisan migrate --force`

I've tried connecting over SSH to the server, and I can manually run the same command without issue.

I just can't understand why the deployment is suddenly having its connection refused. Could it be something to do with the AWS security configuration? Could it expire or something? :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by local settings becoming cached and then deployed to the server in: `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

Clearing the cache with `php artisan config:clear` deleted the file and solved the problem.

Comment: This worked! You saved my life! :D I've searched for says and only old posts keep coming up. For anyone else trying to fix it, I also noticed that if you're logged in as root (e.g. `ec2-user`), running `php artisan config:clear` might not delete the file. Try to manually remove the config files from the cache directory: `sudo rm -f ./bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: Lifesaver :) Thanks a lot!